# The element has no supported sources when assigning video later on execution

Tags: javascript, video

I understand that is a question that has been asked many times but after searching for a long time on "similar questions" none seemed to solve my problem. Here's my situation:

I need to play a video after the user clicks on a "Play Button". I can't use the video's location directly on `src` on the `<video>` tag.

```
<video id="videoPlayer" controls autoplay></video>
```

I also have a VideoPlayer class that handles some information, including the video element.

```
function VideoPlayer(root, play) {
  this._play = play;
  this._root = root;
  this._root.style.display = "none";
}
```

Which is created with:

```
const videoPlayer = new VideoPlayer(document.getElementById("videoPlayer"), document.querySelector("#play"));
```

The second element being the play button.

I've also added to the prototype of `VideoPlayer` a `play` function:

```
VideoPlayer.prototype.play = function (url, immediate) {
  const root = this._root;
  const play = this._play;

  root.style.visibility = "visible";
  root.src = url;

  play.style.display = null;
  once(play, "click", function () {
    root.play();
  });

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    function ok() {
      play.style.display = "none";
      root.style.display = null;
      clear();
    }

    function fail(error) {
      clear();
      reject(error);
    }

    function clear() {
      root.removeEventListener("play", ok);
      root.removeEventListener("abort", fail);
      root.removeEventListener("error", fail);
    }

    root.addEventListener("play", ok);
    root.addEventListener("abort", fail);
    root.addEventListener("error", fail);

    once(root, "ended", function () {
      root.style.display = "none";
      resolve();
    });
  });
};
```

And, after I finally get the video's location, which is something like `videos/video1.mp4` or `videos/video2.mp4` I call the play function using:

```
const initialVideo = "videos/mov_bbb.mp4";
if (initialVideo.length > 0) {
    videoPlayer.play(initialVideo);
}
```

Exactly after calling the function, an error in thrown. After using breaking points I've tracked to this line:

```
root.src = url;
```

The problem doesn't seem to happen with external videos, I've tested using this video from W3School: https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4 and then downloaded the video to use it locally. When it's external it works, when it's local, does not... throwing "The element has no supported sources".

I've tried to export the same video using different codecs and extensions. This problem only happens on Chrome, Mozilla is working just fine. I can access the file via localhost:port/videos/mov_bbb.mp4 but it does not play. I'm using static-server-advance to serve the files. But I've also added to a different server to test it.

My chrome version is: 83.0.4103.10 and I'm not using any extensions.

I'm unable to use php or node.

Comment: Check if the console shows a 404 error in the network tab when you try to set the `src` of your video. Does it download properly?

Comment: It doesn't have a 404, the video is downloaded with a 206.

Comment: Are you able to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to check out?

Comment: Hey, sorry. I was busy. It doesn't get simpler than this: https://gist.github.com/vitorfgd/44c45036f9a2d431924d0e3dfb067e94 You still have to download the video because I didn't know how to share it. But you can download it here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4

Comment: you also need to use a server, like I've said, I'm using static-server-advance.

Comment: Interesting. I've tested on my other machine and it does not work either. It makes it even harder to understand the problem...

Comment: did you tried remote vs local? I commented the line to switch between the two.

Comment: I didn't do that. Looking into it right now.

Comment: Yes, I do now experience the same behavior as you described and tried to make it work with my own JS, but to no avail. But by either opening the `index.html` directly from the file explorer or switching to a different server package does make it work. So my assumption is that the culprit is the static-server-advance package which does not know how to handle local static video files.